# Creating a normal with limits with variable standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

So I was looking into the np.random.norm() function and I understand mean and std.  What I'm looking to do is pick two numbers as limits, for example a mean of 1.0 and I want the numbers to stay between 0.5 and 1.5.  I know that a normal technically goes to infinity both ways, so I'll need to put if statements to control this. What I really want is to adjust the standard deviation programmatically to put anything under 0.5 in the 10th percentile and anything above 1.5 in the 90% percentile (not necessarily 90, but I hope I'm making my point clear).  Could someone direct me in the right direction here?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far, it might be quicker to tell you why its not giving you what you expect rather than us to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy arrays have a .clip() method that sounds sort of what you want:

```
In [4]: np.random.normal(1,.5,20).clip(0.5, 1.5)
Out[4]:
array([ 1.5       ,  1.07224695,  1.13982969,  1.5       ,  0.5       ,
        1.11223533,  0.96127858,  1.5       ,  0.632036  ,  1.23016015,
        0.5       ,  1.22120972,  0.66288919,  0.83533509,  0.90682758,
        1.13052954,  1.30401167,  1.43251102,  0.60045975,  0.9030919 ])
```

If you want that done dynamically to a certain percentile, you can store the array and calculate the percentiles:

```
In [9]: a = np.random.normal(1,.5,20)

In [10]: np.percentile(a, (10, 90))
Out[10]: array([ 0.56384585,  1.68703272])

In [11]: a.clip(*np.percentile(a, (10,90)))
Out[11]:
array([ 1.25908523,  1.58094023,  1.28567188,  0.56384585,  0.74706497,
        1.31853202,  1.47917016,  1.68703272,  0.62015172,  1.18379091,
        1.2165656 ,  1.30725614,  0.64338962,  1.66354559,  0.5804302 ,
        1.68703272,  1.59532039,  0.56384585,  1.21919715,  1.65989337])
```